# Use a DATEDIFF with ALLSELECTED as interval for the DATEADD function

Tags: dax

Goal: A table with three columns:

- date, sessions, previous_sessions.

Situation: I have two slicers interacting with that table:

- Oct 22 to Oct 28 2018 and Nov 5th to Nov 11th 2018.

Issue: My previous_sessions column is blank as I can't figure out the DAX formula. Basically I want to accomplish the following

```
VAR datediffs = DATEDIFF(ALLSELECTED('Date'[Date]),ALLSELECTED('Previous Date'[Date]),DAY) 
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Table[Sessions]),
    USERELATIONSHIP('Previous Date'[Date],'Date'[Date]),
    DATEADD('Date'[Date],-datediffs,DAY)
    )
```

the datediffs variable should do Nov 11 - oct 28 and give 14 days and that would be the number in the interval argument in the `DATEADD` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DATEDIFF` function expects a scalar for its first arguments, not a column or table.

You'll want to take a max over the respective slicer selections.

```
VAR datediffs =
    DATEDIFF(
        CALCULATE (
            MAX ( 'Date'[Date] ),
            ALLSELECTED ( 'Date'[Date] )
        )
        CALCULATE (
            MAX ( 'Previous Date'[Previous Date] ),
            ALLSELECTED ( 'Previous Date'[Previous Date] )
        )
    )
```

I'm not sure if the `RETURN` part will work as you expect, but that should give the proper interval for the `DATEADD` function.

Comment: for some reason the previous sale of Nov 5th gives me Nov 13th, for Nov 6th it gives me Nov 15th. its adding 8 days with a step of 1 day.It should decrease by 14 days...

Comment: I need to force the previous_sessions column to be the value of current_session -14 days but doesnt seem theres a function for that